# iPad SDK in Leopard

Tags: iphone, ipad, osx-leopard

Is there any way to install the iPad SDK on a Leopard machine?

Comment: the update is nice and cheap, pretty simple too, unless your using a hackintosh :)

Comment: As Aran says, the upgrade is only $29, so there's really no good reason NOT to upgrade ;-)

Comment: The upgrade may make your system either faster or a lot sh!ttier (like my 2008 Mac mini) :(

Answer (score 4):

It's only for Snow Leopard. You had to upgrade your system first.

Comment: yes, what you said is correct. Now i have iPad application development environment in my mini mac having Snow Lepard.

Answer (score 0):

The 3.2 SDK is currently under a non-disclosure agreement. The best place to ask questions about it is Apple's Developer Forum (there's a section specifically for the beta).

But in general, if there's no download listed on the developer site, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there's SDK 3.2 beta with XCode 3.1.3, which works on Leopard and SDK 3.2 beta with XCode 3.2.2, which only works on Leopard. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: That is true for SDK 3.1 but not for the 3.2 (iPad SDK).